# Remove the querystring on url by facebook comment box on my site

Tags: javascript, facebook, query-string, facebook-comments

i need to remove the querystring that come when someone uses the facebook comment box on my site. Their friends see a link to a whole new page with no comments. Please let me know the full javascript and html to use. http://vhdmedia.com/detail/B005DLP0GK

Answer (score 0):

Oh, i found out this: http://records.photodharma.net/computing/facebook-comments-dynamic-urls-on-static-pages/comment-page-1#comment-49477 and added my contribution to it!